# Cocoapods - Adding Cedar library breaks compilation / linker

Tags: objective-c, linker, cocoapods

We have an Xcode project, that's using CocoaPods to manage the dependencies. So far, we had lots of common libraries like AFNetworking, OCMock for testing etc.

We also have another internal C++ library, a `.a` file that our software is linked against at compile time. All of this **works fine**.

Now I want to add the Cedar library, via CocoaPods. Easy peazy: `pod 'Cedar', '~> 0.9'`, `pod install` and voilà! The Cedar library is added to the pods, and I'm ready to compile.

But then, for a reason I can't understand, there's a problem while linking with our custom `.a` library. The linker complains that it cannot find specific methods in the library. The rest looks fine, although I can't be 100% sure of it.

There's no change in the main project file. No different flag, no different search path... Only the pod project has been updated. Sadly I can't disclose too many details about that library, but I'll try to provide what's necessary.

Does this look familiar to any of you? What could have gone wrong?

Comment: Its probably @murat 's answer. But what methods can't be found? I've had a namespace collision (or something) when using Cedar with Boost C++ before.

Answer (score 2):

It is probably because your app is now linked with `libc++` whereas your internal library is linked with `libstdc++`. Try to rebuild your internal library with `libc++`. If that is not an option use  0.8.1 version of Cedar, I believe it uses `libstdc++`

Comment: Looks interesting. I'll have a look.

Comment: Ok, so apparently that's why. It's not an option to switch to `libc++`, and Cedar 0.8.1 doesn't compile (returning from void functions and stuff). Any idea?

Comment: @Antoine_935 You are right. Cedar 0.8.1 does not compile and I don't think you can compile latest Cedar with libstdc++. Sorry, I am out of ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Could it possibly be this? The cocoapods specs repository was broken a few days ago, as detailed 
[here](http://blog.cocoapods.org/Repairing-Our-Broken-Specs-Repository/). (Go there for the long story).

Short story, it is broken, fix it like this:

```
$ pod repo remove master
$ pod setup
```

Comment: Doesn't sound related in this case.

Comment: Encountered that error earlier in the day ;) Thanks for raising !